# Django admin -- how to make stackedinline field clickable

Tags: django-admin

I have a url that I want to make clickable in Django admin.

```
class someAdmin(StackedInline):
    fields = ('get_download_link', )
    readonly_fields = ('get_download_link',)
```

I noticed that I need to have `readonly_fields` to include the custom field or else Django complains.

I then add the custom field

```
    def get_download_link(self, obj):
        massaged_link = massage_the_link(obj.link) # pre-process the link
        return "<a href='%s'>Download</a>" % massaged_link
```

the html is not effective. I got everything as one big ass string. How do I make this a clickable link?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently all I need to do is to wrap the string with `mark_safe`

doc here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe

and then the html tag will take effect